# google cloud doesn't work with previous f-string python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, f-string

I'm trying to connect to google cloud and i've set the python code as follows:

```
import google.cloud import storage

bucket_id='my_bucketname'
//others variables
storage=f'gs://{bucket_id}/'

client = storage.Client()
```

But, I've had the error:

```
client = storage.Client()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

I've noticed when I comment the variables with f-string(or using .format() as well), it works.
These tests I did, there is no variable related with the method storage.Client() and even so occours the error.

I tested in 3.6 and 3.8 python versions with same errors.

Comment: Youre importing "storage" but shadowing it with a variable called the same name.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? If you assign a string to a variable, that variable holds a string – which doesn't have a ``Client`` attribute. What *else* did you expect and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code imports the Google Cloud SDK into an object named **storage**.

```
import google.cloud import storage
```

You then declare a string named **storage** with the contents of the bucket name. This overwrites the previous line of code.

```
storage=f'gs://{bucket_id}/'
```

You are then trying to create a Cloud Storage Client object from a string object:

```
client = storage.Client()
```

That results in the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

Solution: use different variable names:

```
import google.cloud import storage

bucket_name='my_bucketname'
//others variables
bucket_uri=f'gs://{bucket_id}/'

client = storage.Client()
```

Comment: Ow my.....I didn't realize this....I spend 5 hours to try solve this issue and I didn't see same name! Thanks very much John for your patience to asnwer my question!